# Creating a custom SAS date time format using ISO 8601 notation

Tags: date, datetime, sas, format, iso

I have a character variable in a SAS table that is populated with a non-usual type of date time. Indeed, it has the following format : `YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000+00:00`. Here is an example: `2020-01-01T00:00:00`.

I want to transform this character column to a date column. I have been searching in the documentation an associated format but did not find the correct one.

I found `$E8601DZ.` ([$E8601DZ. format](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=vdmmlcdc&cdcVersion=1.0&docsetId=leforinforref&docsetTarget=n1nvxddoqjof57n1r6j02unvwm8o.htm&locale=en)) which results for example in: `2020-01-01T00:00:00+00.00` (notice the `.000` missing after the seconds) and `$E8601DTw.d` ([$E8601DTw.d format](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=leforinforref&docsetTarget=n03vr57gdozvean1klfaaa14c9c0.htm&docsetVersion=1.0&locale=en)) which results for example in: `2020-01-01T00:00:00.000` (notice the `+00:00` missing).

Thus, would it be possible to "mix" those two formats resulting in a custom format that will create a date variable with the desired format ?

`SAS Code`:

```
data example;
   date="2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00";
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the right informat to read the data and the right format to write the data.  If the offset is always zero use the E8601DZ format/informat. To include three decimal places just make sure to specify that is what you want.  The total width of the generated string is 29 characters of which 3 are to the right of the decimal point, so use `e8601dz29.3` format specification.  You do not want to include the decimal width in the INFORMAT as the meaning of decimal places on an informat is different than on a format, so use `e8601dz29.` as the informat specification.

```
data example;
   string="2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00";
   datetime=input(string,e8601dz29.);
   format datetime datetime19.;
   string2=put(datetime,e8601dz29.3);
   put (_all_) (=/);
run;
```

Results:

```
string=2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
datetime=01JAN2020:00:00:00
string2=2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You state you have a character variable containing values that are a date time representation.

The format you link to **is not a character format**, and thus would **not** be prefaced with a `$`.  Per docs the format

> Writes datetime values for the zero meridian

Datetime values fundamentally are numbers.

You might want to perform an `input` to convert the character value to an actual SAS datetime value (numeric seconds from epoch `01jan1960T0:0:0`), and then apply an ISO datetime format to that variable that is receiving the datetime value.

Example:

```
data have;
  my_datetime_string = '2020-01-01T00:00:00';
run;

data want;
  set have;
  my_sas_datetime = input (my_datetime_string, E8601DT.);
  my_sas_datepart = datepart(my_sas_datetime);

  format my_sas_datetime datetime19.;
  format my_sas_datepart date9.;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

[image]